# How to translate SQL "CHECK" and "COALESCE" to Entity Framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and this is working code in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE likes 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    post_id INTEGER REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    comment_id INTEGER REFERENCES comments(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CHECK(
            COALESCE((post_id)::BOOLEAN::INTEGER, 0)
            +
            COALESCE((comment_id)::BOOLEAN::INTEGER, 0)
            = 1
        ),
    UNIQUE(user_id, post_id, comment_id)
);
```

Thanks Panagiotis.

I change the database schema as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwpHz.png)

Comment: You can use migrations but you should probably *not* use your ORM, *any* ORM, to design your database. ORMs are meant to Map Objects to Relational data, not replace the database. Migrations can handle only simple deployment scenarios, mainly adding columns and tables. They can't handle eg splitting one column into many, dropping columns etc, stuff that requires modifying data. The database will be used by *many* applications, not just a single one.

Comment: Besides, there are far better ways to ensure that one of `post_id` or `comment_id` is selected at a time. Including *not* using a single table `likes` to represent two different relations. You gain nothing by this and end up making your C# code harder - how are you going to represent those likes in the `User` object? It's better to have separate `Comment_Likes` and `Post_Likes` tables, allowing you to easily add `LikedComments` and `LikedPosts` to the `User` object.